# Remove DebugKit markup from a view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5, cakephp-debug-kit

I have a *.ctp template with some HTML that's aimed to be converted into PDF with the [CakePDF](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf/tree/1.0.3#configuration) plugin. In the development phase I have set CakePHP debug level to `2` and that causes all DebugKig stuff to show up in the rendered view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/debug_kit/css/debug_toolbar.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.DEBUGKIT_JQUERY_URL = "/debug_kit/js/jquery.js";
//]]>
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="/debug_kit/js/js_debug_toolbar.js"></script>
```

```
<div id="debug-kit-toolbar">[...]</div>
```

I don't need it and most PDF engines go berserk with it. Is there a way to get rid of it, either in this specific view or in all PDF templates?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured out a per-case solution. You can disable the component at the end of the action method inside the controller (anywhere before `$this->render()` gets called):

```
$this->Components->unload('DebugKit.Toolbar');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to debug mode off for a particular pdf controller like this

```
 public function beforeFilter() { 
    parent::beforeFilter();
    Configure::write('debug', 0);
 }
```

You can also unload dubug component for particular controller or action try this

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    if(in_array($this->action, array('index'))) {
        $this->Components->unload('DebugKit.Toolbar');
    }
}
```

This will unload debug component in index function for particular controller

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But I still want to see error messages and other debug information.